# DXA - Get published settings through Graphql

Tags: dxa, sites-9, graphql, pca

Pardon my limited knowledge (or rather lack of) of GraphQL, but I wasn't able to find a way to retrieve values that are added through DXA's Publish Settings using just graphs.

I was able to retrieve the variant URL of the binary of interest, but is there a direct way to get the actual content of the variant without opening a web client to the DXA website using the variant URL? I need the values in a non-public area of my architecture and if possible, I would like to avoid opening a channel to the presentation server.

```
binaryComponent(namespaceId:1 publicationId: 481 binaryId: 100431){
    id
    title
    variants{
      edges {
        node{
          url
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up going a different way. Instead of trying to get the labels/configuration externally, now I'm pushing them from DXA to the consuming applications.

Way to obtain the settings within DXA:

```
string websiteConfiguration = SiteConfiguration.ContentProvider.
    GetStaticContentItem("/system/config/myModule.json",WebRequestContext.Localization).GetText()
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK - you could use **downloadUrl** to download the binary from the content service.

Alternatively, you can use the item filter query to get all the binaries in that publication which will give you all the binaries.

```
{
  items(filter: {itemTypes: [COMPONENT], publicationIds: 16225}) {
    edges {
      node {
        itemId
        publicationId
        ... on Component {
          multiMedia
        }
        ... on BinaryComponent {
          title
          multiMedia
          variants {
            edges {
              node {
                variantId
                path                
                type
                url
                downloadUrl 
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** This query for BinaryComponent expansion not working in 9.5 GA, you need the latest HF in content service.

Comment: Not working unfortunately. (possibly because the version of CD)